# Pass pinch gesture from custom UIView to parent UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7

I've got a custom `UIView` as a subview in a `UIScrollView`.

When `selected`, the user can resize the subview by pinching anywhere on the screen (the sub view is fairly small).

When `deselected`, I would like this pinch gesture to be passed on to the UIScrollView so that it can handle it as it normally does.

Here is what I'm trying.

```
- (IBAction)pinchInView:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    if (self.item.isSelected) 
    {
        if ((sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) || (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded))
        {
            [self.item resizeWithScaleFactor:sender.scale];
        }
    } else 
    {
        [self.scrollView setZoomScale:self.scrollView.zoomScale *= sender.scale];
    }
    sender.scale = 1;
}
```

While it does work, it seems an awkward way to go about this.

Is there a way to let the UIScrollView handle its own **zooming**?

I'm pretty much using the same approach with pan gestures as well.

If there is any way to make this less awkward, I'd really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a Delegate to the Gestures which You have added to subview. Implement following Method in delegate

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecoznizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{
    if(isSelected == true)
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
    }
```

Comment: Just to be safer, I would also save the `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` in an instance variable of that class and make sure the `UIGestureRecognizer` coming into `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` is our gesture recognizer. But overall I suport this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the below delegate method

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
```